# Url rewrite [.htaccess] convert

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i have a web.config of iis server and i need to convert the redirect to apache [.htaccess]
I try to do this and I success to get this:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/.+?\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$ https://XX/YY%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I get redirect to "HTTPS/xx/yy/wp-content/uploads"
but I need to get this path:
"HTTPS/xx/yy/uploads" - same without wp-content.
how can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^wp-content/(uploads/)(.+?)\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$ https://XX/YY/$1/$2.$3 [R=301,L]` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* that excludes the `wp-content/` prefix and use this in the *substitution* string, instead of `REQUEST_URI`, which contains the entire URL-path.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/(uploads/.+\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg))$ https://XX/YY/$1 [R=301,L]
```

No need for the non-greedy quantifier in the middle (ie. `.+?`) - it is marginally more efficient without.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached by the browser.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.